# Нерекурсивный обход бинарного дерева без стека

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, бинарное-дерево, структуры-данных

Необходимо построить нерекурсивный алгоритм обхода бинарного дерева, обладающий следующими свойствами:

- Дерево из n узлов обходится за время O(n);
- Объем дополнительной памяти (кроме той, которая выделяется под дерево) не превышает некоторой константы;
- В процессе выполнения алгоритма дерево нельзя модифицировать даже временно.

Единственное, что смог найти по теме - обход Морриса, но данный алгоритм временно преобразует дерево в "прошитое" дерево, поэтому не подходит.

Comment: в нодах есть ссылка на родителя?

Comment: Скажите научруку, пусть диссертацию сам пишет, а не аспирантов припахивает.

Comment: @PashaPash: Допустим, да.

Comment: @VladD: Это не диссертация, я хочу разобраться с упражнением из книги Кормена. По условию константа ограничена глобально.

Comment: @DarkGenius: А, Кормен, тогда понятно, возражение снимается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ссылка на родителя есть - то можно взять алгоритм из ответа [How to do in-order traversal of a BST without recursion or stack but using parent pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372118/1988244)

```
static void Walk(Node node)
{
    Node lastNode = null;
    while (node != null)
    {
        if (lastNode == node.Parent)
        {
            if (node.Left != null)
            {
                lastNode = node;
                node = node.Left;
                continue;
            }
            else
                lastNode = null;
        }
        if (lastNode == node.Left)
        {
            Output(node);

            if (node.Right != null)
            {
                lastNode = node;
                node = node.Right;
                continue;
            }
            else
                lastNode = null;
        }
        if (lastNode == node.Right)
        {
            lastNode = node;
            node = node.Parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Но, строго говоря, в BST ссылки на родителя нет, и обойти его без модификации дерева и с лимитом на память нельзя.

Comment: Как доказать, что нельзя?

Comment: @DarkGenius очень легко. Алгоритим в процессе обхода дерева из N нод может находится в N различных состояниях. т.к. дерево модифицировать нельзя, то для описания состояния требуется дополнительной памяти log2(N) бит. Приведенный выше алгоритм не попадает под требования - он не заработает на количестве нод > 2^32 - т.к. он хранит состояние как int32.

Comment: @DarkGenius ну а если расход памяти log2(N) бит приемлем (читерство!), то достаточно просто написать функцию, которая будет идти по дереву, считать ноды (нерекурсивно), и выводить N-ю ноду. И вызвать ее с параметром от 1 до N. Т.е. теоретически лимит будет нарушаться, но на практике - нет (потому что такое дерево просто не влезет в память).

Comment: Эээ... Ну то, что указатель 32-битный, это читерство немного. Дерево с к-вом узлов > 2^32 нельзя даже представить в указанном виде, не то что обойти, т. к. на каждый узел должен быть указатель.

Comment: @VladD да, я об этом честно написал в комменте выше :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Насколько я понимаю, по сути вашему алгоритму не нужен указатель, достаточно флага, указывающего, с какой стороны мы пришли в текущий узел (сверху => обходим листья, снизу-слева => обходим правую ветку, снизу-справа => идём вверх). То есть 2 бита. Заработает на любом числе нод, только бы в память машины влезло.

Comment: @VladD да, но это работает толко за счет указателя на родителя - т.е. это просто обход неориентированного графа без циклов. в нем вершины можно пронумеровать так, что находясь в вершине M можно однозначно дойти по ребрам вершины M+1. а в ор-графе по ребрам от M до M+1 дойти нельзя - значит придется где-то хранить информацию о возврате.

Comment: @VladD с другой стороны, дерево обычно определяют как "связный ациклический граф", так что можно спокойно рассчитывать на то, что ссылка на родителя есть - граф же связный.

Comment: @PashaPash: Угу, я согласен насчёт дерева, да. Без указателя на родительский элемент ничего не выйдет. Я просто не вполне уверен в доказательстве насчёт дополнительной памяти. Если учитывать размер указателя, то для случая с указателем на предка не подходит даже ваш алгоритм, т. к. он пользуется переменной `node` не ограниченного сверху размера.

Comment: @VladD проклятая математика :) куда не ткнись - сплошная безысходность.