# Итератор для бинарного дерева

Tags: java

Всем привет. Задача реализовать бинарное дерево поиска. Обязательное условие реализовать итератор. Уже несколько дней пытаюсь найти решение, гугл не помогает, везде в основном примеры методов для вывода на печать всех элементов, но мне нужно реализовать именно итератор, с методами next и hasNext. Буду очень признателен за вербальный алгоритм, и бесконечно благодарен за пример в коде. 
P.S. Метод add() реализован, элементы корректно добавляются.

```
 @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
      int expectedModCount = modCount;
       return new Iterator<E>() {
        BinNode<E> curr = root;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return curr != null;
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            checkModCount();
            //todo
             return ;
        }


        private void checkModCount() {
            if (expectedModCount != modCount) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: на основе чего вы пишите дерево? На массиве, листе, связном списке, нодах... В общем **"Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе."**

Comment: Дерево на нодах. Нода содержит правый и левые элементы а так же ссылку на родителя.

Comment: а пример ноды то где? кода ноды, как у вас связаны элементы? как обратиться к следующему или предыдущему?

Answer (score 2):

Давайте заменим java на автомастерскую. "Ребят, собрал машину, двигатель впихнул, ездит. Вот только тормоза не могу запилить. Облазил весь интернет, а там только показывают как двери менять. Машина обычная - на колесах, они такие крутятся и она вперед-назад". Не надо так ) Понял ваш вопрос только потому что сам когда то учился в универе.

```
class Node {
     Object value;
     Node left, right;
}
```

Я так понимаю ваша проблема, заключается в том, что вы знаете как реализовывать классический рекурсивный вариант:

```
void go(Node root) {
    go(root.left);
    go(root.right);
}
```

А он не ложится на стандартный итартор. Проблема в том, что вам нужно сделать обход не рекурсивным. А для этого придется сохранять путь назад вручную (в случае с рекурсией, он сохраняется в стеке, я думаю ошибка StackOverflow вам знакома).

В общем чтобы не изобретать велосипед, [уже был похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458703/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: Не вижу причин, почему рекурсивный обход не годится для итератора.

Comment: Напишите итератор,реализующий стандартный интерфейс Iterator, основаный на рекурсии, если сможете - обязательно напишите.